# Getting 502 Bad gateway - Nginx & Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to setup Nginx with Gunicorn and Django but getting 502 bad gateway error. Below are my files.

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/apio/apio/
ExecStart=/root/sweetapi_env/bin/gunicorn \
         --access-logfile - \
         --workers 3 \
         --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
        apio.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My nginx.conf file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name MY_IP_ADDRESS;
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }

}
```

My Folder structure

```
apio
    apio
        db.sqlite3
        manage.py
        static
        apio
            settings.py
            wsgi.py
            urls.py
            __init__.py
```

On hitting my IP Address I am getting below in /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2020/05/15 12:08:15 [error] 31068#31068: *1 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while 
connecting to upstream, client: 117.203.***.***, server: ***.**.**.**, 
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/"
```

My gunicorn.socket test is also failing

```
gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Fri 2020-05-15 11:58:41 UTC; 12min ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
```

Please provide some pointers. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Guess Gunicorn wasn't correctly installed inside the virtual env. My Gunicorn.socket logs gave me the clue.

```
sudo journalctl -u gunicorn
May 15 11:19:34 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 systemd[29716]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
May 15 11:19:34 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 systemd[29716]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /root/sweetapi_env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
```