# Getting 502 Bad Gateway NGINX/Jenkins

Tags: nginx

This is similar to [Getting 502 Bad gateway - Nginx & Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818965/getting-502-bad-gateway-nginx-gunicorn) but not quite. I don't see any logs in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` nor `/var/log/nginx/error.log` files.

If I use the default `nginx.conf` file, I can access at least the NGINX service on a browser using `https://NGINX_IP_address`, but if I use my `nginx.conf` file that aims to forward requests to our Jenkins server, I get a 502. **NOTE**: I can access the `https://Jenkins_IP_address` from the same browser, so I know the Jenkins service is running.

Here's my `nginx.conf` files that serves a `502.`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # HTTP(S) server
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         NGINX_IP_address;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/private.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        error_log           /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        if ($scheme != "https") {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        ### Proxy to Jenkins
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://jenkins_trust/;
        }
    }

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Jenkins server
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    upstream jenkins_trust {
        #ip_hash;
        server <Jenkins_IP_address>:443;
        keepalive 64;
    }
```

Any clues? Thanks!